# Calculating CPU Times For Each CPU Individually

Tags: windows, kernel, cpu-usage

Windows Task Manager shows the **user** and **kernel** times for each CPU in the system.

However, every function I have researched in the Win32 API returns only the times for all CPU's cumulatively

The only function that gives numbers for each CPU is `GetProcessorSystemCycleTime()`, but it is defined as:

`Retrieves the cycle time each processor in the specified processor
group spent executing deferred procedure calls (DPCs) and interrupt
service routines (ISRs) since the processor became active.`

And I don't think that is what I want.

How does Task Manager calculate the **user** and **kernel** times for each CPU individually?